# Prove $\lvert q\alpha - p \rvert \gt \frac cq $ using real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $\sqrt 2$ exists, and let $a=\sqrt 2$. Prove that there exists a number $c > 0$ such that for all integers $q,p$, and $q\neq0$ we have $$\lvert q\alpha - p \rvert \gt \frac cq $$

Note: The same $c$ should work for all $q,p$. Try rationalizing $q\alpha - q$, i.e. take the product $(q\alpha - p)(q\alpha + p)$, show that it is an integer $\neq0$, so that its absolute value is $\ge 1$. Estimate $q\alpha + p$.

The problem is that i don't understant why is $(q\alpha - p)(q\alpha + p) \neq0$

Comment: Because $α=\sqrt2$ is not rational. On the other hand, $2^2·2-3^2=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $p > 0, q>0$ only.
For all $p > 2 * \alpha q$, we have
$$ |\alpha q - p | = p - \alpha q > \alpha q$$
For p such that $p \le  2 \alpha q$, we use the hint that
$$ |(\alpha q - p )^2| \ge 1 $$,

we have 
$$|\alpha q - p| \ge \frac{1}{|\alpha q + p|} > \frac{1}{\alpha q + 2 \alpha q} = \frac{1}{3\alpha}\frac{1}{q}$$
Let $ c = \frac{1}{3\alpha}$, clearly,
$$\alpha q > \frac{c}{q} $$ 
Since q is an positive integer.
So for the case p where $p > 2 * \alpha q$, we alrerady have
$$ |\alpha q - p | = p - \alpha q > \alpha q > \frac{c}{q}$$

Combining both cases, for all $p > 0, q > 0$ we have

$$ |\alpha q - p| > \frac{c}{q} $$, where $c = \frac{1}{3\alpha}$

Simlilarly, we can carry out the same proof when at one of p or q is negative.

QED